# Software tool as in Bret Victor's demo

Tags: student-motivation, student-perceptions, lecture-tools

Already last year I encountered the great http://worrydream.com/LearnableProgramming/ and it was much needed fresh air (while I was suffocating in my provided "textbooks": cobbled collections of random things difficult to follow). But for some reason I didn't appreciate it fully. I read it again now and, wow, it's so wonderful that I can't really express how I appreciate this thorough and lucid thought style.

Well my point is now a bit more mundane. The examples in the essay look very real, but I couldn't find any reference to the tool used, I only understood (from different sources) that it's Bret's own creation. I would like to use it directly or as a starting point for further work as it looks so well done and it is a *lot* of work. It would without doubt benefit the students infinitely. I would even pay for it.

I found choc: https://www.newline.co/choc. But it seems to be partial and missing at least the abstraction of vars and functions (see the essay).

Anyway, just to be clear and explicit: thanks a lot to Bret for making what is arguably the best tool for computer science teaching I have ever seen, going *really* to the fundamental needs of students.

Comment: Instead of linking to the whole essay, could you take some screencaps of the diagrams you're looking to recreate? That'd make it easier on potential answerers. Some of us are afraid of links to sites we don't recognize, and diagrams are really all that's needed to answer the question.

Comment: Good questions here tend to be quite "self contained".

Comment: I've been to that site before; I used to love it, I now probably disagree with more than I agree with.  Nevertheless, he has interesting ways of thinking about instruction.  I'm not sure, though, what you're asking for.  Is the question that you're looking for Bret's source code?

Comment: Ben, yes of course :) it seems to be a real tool, my experience with this kind of things is that such a tool would be made available as open source. I start wondering this is not such a case but it would be sad given its potential. I am curious anyway on why you disagree, it might spark even more interesting thoughts.

Comment: I don't understand the other previous comments, sorry.

Comment: @user9137 Sorry for being unclear, I was trying to ask you to copy some of the examples from the essay into your post.

Comment: It would be quite difficult to copy, for how rich it is. Anyway I think it would not really help much: my original question was if someone knows where to find the tool, it implies prior knowledge of its identity: not knowing what it is sure implies not knowing where to get it :)